# Sequence Pattern in matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, sequence

I have a large matrix

```
#  id    v1   v2   v3   v4   v5   v6   v7   v8
# 1001   37   15   30   37    4   11   35   37
# 2111   44   31   44   30   24   39   44   18
# 3121   43   49   39   34   44   43   26   24
# 4532   45   31   26   33   12   47   37   15
# 5234   23   27   34   23   30   34   23    4
# 6345   9    46   39   34    8   43   26   24
```

I would like to identify sequences that start and end with the same number.
Example of a sequence below:

Output:

```
1001 [v1] to [v4] 37 to 37: 15,30
1001 [v4] to [v8] 37 to 37: 4, 11, 35
2111 [v1] to [v3] 44 to 44: 31 
2111 [v3] to [v7] 44 to 44: 30, 24, 39
```

I would like to know the numbers that follow 37 and the frequent number that precedes 37 in this case is 15.

Comment: Does the sequence have to be going across the rows or can it be vertical?

Comment: @qdread thank you across the rows

Comment: What about wrapping around from first to last column?

Comment: @qdread Could you be a little bit more specific please

Comment: For example in your matrix, row 6, can you say 26, 24, 9 follows 43 (going from column 7 to 8 to 1)?

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(mat[1:6, 1:8])` where `mat` is the name of your matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to do it across the rows of the matrix you can use apply and which to identify where in each row is a number equal to the one you want (43 in your example). Code goes as follow:

```
equal.43 = apply(mat==43,1,which)
```

This will give you a list where each element in the list corresponds to each row of the matrix, and inside these elements you will have the column number which contains the value. For example, imagine your matrix goes as following:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    5   10   10
[2,]    7    5    6   10
[3,]   10    7    5    5
[4,]    6    8   10    9
[5,]    2    5    7   10
```

Then you run the command:

```
where.is.7 = apply(x==7,1,which)
```

If you inspect where.is.7, you will see:

```
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
integer(0)

[[5]]
[1] 3
```

Meaning, the 1st row has no 7's, the 2nd row has one in the 1st column, and so forth. From there you can loop through the list to identify whatever "neighbors" you want. Additionally, before the loop, you should drop any column value which will give you  subscript out of bounds error. For example,

```
where.is.7 = lapply(where.is.7,function(x) x[x<4])
followers = c()
for(i in 1:5){

  if(length(where.is.7[[i]])>0){
    followers = cbind(followers,x[i,where.is.7[[i]]+1])
  }
}
```